# Bayesian AB testing for Bernoulli Events with Time Patterns

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, ab-test

I have read in [this paper](https://vwo.com/downloads/VWO_SmartStats_technical_whitepaper.pdf), about how to do Bayesian AB testing for conversions in digital advertising. One can start with uniform priors, and update them to Beta distributions based on `num_trials_A`, `num_successes_A`, `num_trials_B` and `num_successes_B`.

However it seems that the authors take the conversion rates to be constants there. What if there is some seasonality, or a trend in the rates over time?
Is there something about modifying the test for this in the literature?

My intuition is to check whether I can get this seasonality/trend to go away by taking the difference between the two sample rates.